# xsim: What is the correct way to count exercises per section?

Tags: counters, xsim, count

What is the correct way to count exercises per section like

[image]

I got it with

```
% Count exercises per section =====
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\setcounter{exercise}{0}%
\oldsection}
```

*but is there a function inside `xsim`?*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise},
}
% Count exercises per section =====
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\setcounter{exercise}{0}%
\oldsection}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{exercise}
An exercise in section 1
\end{exercise}

\section{Second  section}

\begin{exercise}
An exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Another exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Another exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xsim` package provides the option `exercise/within` that determines when the exercise counter is reset, see page 20 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/xsim_manual.pdf).

Code:

```
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise},
exercise/within = section
}
```

Comment: Ah,  very good! ;)

Comment: Which is just a wrapper around the kernel macro `\counterwithin` :)